# Watermark on the first page only

Tags: watermark

I'm modified the following code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7400/watermark-on-first-page-in-left-margin-like-arxiv) to add a couple of vertical watermarks on a page. However, the code places these watermarks on *every* page.

Is there a way to restrict watermarking to the first page or certain pages of my `amsbook`?

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}%
\setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight}%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
\protect{\put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
\makebox(-515,0){\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor[gray]{0.90}%
   {\Huge Draft:  \today}}}
\makebox(515,0){\rotatebox{270}{\textcolor[gray]{0.90}%
   {\Huge  Draft:  \today}}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hi
\newpage
Hi, again.

\end{document}
```

Comment: a quick solution for those using draftwatermark: `\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark} \SetWatermarkText{Draft} \SetWatermarkScale{1}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package allows you to do this easily; simply use the `some` package option together with the `\BgThispage` command for those pages which should exhibit the watermark; the package also allows you to control all the aspects of the watermark (opacity, color, scale, placement, etc.). A little example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[some]{background}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgContents{\parbox{10cm}{%
  \Huge Draft:  \today\\[14cm]\rotatebox{180}{\Huge Draft:  \today}}}
\SetBgColor{gray}
\SetBgAngle{270}
\SetBgOpacity{0.2}

\begin{document}

Hi\BgThispage
\newpage
Hi, again.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use directly **atbegshi**

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}

\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
\protect{\put(.5\paperwidth,-.5\paperheight){%
\makebox(-515,0){\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor[gray]{0.90}%
   {\Huge Draft:  \today}}}%
\makebox(515,0){\rotatebox{270}{\textcolor[gray]{0.90}%
   {\Huge  Draft:  \today}}}}}}}

\begin{document}

Hi
\newpage
Hi, again.

\end{document}
```

A simpler code, that avoids guessing the number 515 is

```
\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \Huge
  \put(1cm,-.5\paperheight){%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textcolor[gray]{0.90}{Draft: \today}}}%
  \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm-\ht\strutbox\relax,-.5\paperheight){%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\textcolor[gray]{0.90}{Draft: \today}}}%
}}
```

Or, with **eso-pic**,

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
\protect{\put(.5\paperwidth,.5\paperheight){%
\makebox(-515,0){\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor[gray]{0.90}%
   {\Huge Draft:  \today}}}%
\makebox(515,0){\rotatebox{270}{\textcolor[gray]{0.90}%
   {\Huge  Draft:  \today}}}}}\ClearShipoutPictureBG}

\begin{document}

Hi
\newpage
Hi, again.

\end{document}
```

Note that the **picture** package allows for directly using dimensions in the `picture` commands.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a command that I use frequently for watermarks. It also uses `eso-pic`. It puts the contents at the center of the text block.

- `\WaterMark{<picture>}` - puts watermark on ever page (can be stopped with `\ClearShipoutPictureBG`)
- `\WaterMark*{<picture>}` - puts watermark on single page

It is also useful if you want to put a logo watermark on every page (use Gimp to downtone the picture)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\WaterMark{%
    \@ifstar{\@WaterMarkS}{\@watermark}}
\newcommand\@WaterMark[1]{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtTextCenter{\NullGrphBox{#1}}}}
\newcommand\@WaterMarkS[1]{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtTextCenter{\NullGrphBox{#1}}}}
\newcommand\NullGrphBox[1]{%
    \parbox[c]{0pt}{\makebox[0pt][c]{#1}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\draftpictA{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
        \makebox(-180,0){\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor[gray]{0.10}%
            {\Huge Draft:  \today}}}
        \makebox(180,0){\rotatebox{270}{\textcolor[gray]{0.10}%
            {\Huge  Draft:  \today}}}
    \end{picture}}

\newcommand\draftpictB{%
     \rotatebox[origin=c]{60}{\scalebox{15}{%
        \textcolor[gray]{0.90}{\textbf{DRAFT}}}}}

\begin{document}
\WaterMark*{\draftpictB}
Hi
\newpage
Hi, again.
\newpage
xx
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommended to use [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) for such things. If `watermark.pdf` is the (LaTeX generated) watermark (1 page) with an additional empty page and `mydocument.pdf` is the (may be LaTeX generated) own document, you can can "watermark" it:

```
pdftk mydocument.pdf multibackground watermark.pdf output mydocumentwatermark.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following, which does what I want, and seems to satisfy your needs as well:

```
 \usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
  \definecolor{LtGrey}{rgb}{0.975,0.975,0.975}

  \AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtTextCenter{%
  \makebox(0,0)[c]{\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
   \rotatebox{45}{\textsf{\textbf{\color{LtGrey}DRAFT}}}}}
 }
}
```

If you want the 'draft' watermark on the first page only, simply use the asterisk as shown below:

```
 \AddToShipoutPicture*{%
```

Comment: Seems to be simular to egregs answer? Only the star version is new.