# Making arXiv-style watermark on every page

Tags: arxiv, watermark

I want to make a watermark on every page of my document in the style of arXiv, except I want the watermark on the right-hand side of the pages.

I'm trying to adapt the example from [watermark on first page in left margin (like arXiv)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7400/watermark-on-first-page-in-left-margin-like-arxiv), but I don't know how to tweak this to get what I need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
{
    \node at ($(current page.west)+(20.5,0)$) [rotate=90] {\Huge\textcolor{gray}{Draft: \today}};
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It turns out you can just use the [draftwatermark](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/draftwatermark?lang=en) package instead, e.g. replace the tikz commands in the question with something like:

```
\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\SetWatermarkText{Draft: \today}
\SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.5}
\SetWatermarkFontSize{1cm}
\SetWatermarkAngle{90}
\SetWatermarkHorCenter{20cm}
```

Answer (score 0):

Package options during the invocation of [draftwatermark](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/draftwatermark?lang=en) can also be used for a page-agnostic approach over the current solution.

```
\usepackage[hpos=0.98\paperwidth, % .98 to prevent bleed
            vpos=0.5\paperwidth,
            angle=90]{draftwatermark}
```

Attached: [Complete Documentation](https://mirror.ufs.ac.za/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/draftwatermark/draftwatermark.pdf)